# Custom CSS class not working

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I have added custom CSS to style.css file on my own custom skin in Wordpress 3.9.2. All classes seem to be working fine, apart from the new ones that I have added.

```
.frontpage_tile {
    width: 270px;
    float: left;
    min-height: 1px;
    margin-left: 30px;
}

.block {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}

.block img {
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid rgba(53, 53, 53, 0.65);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-radius: 3px;
}

.block .caption {
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 1.2em;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 1px;
    left: 1px;
    right: 1px;
    color: #FFF;
    background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #000, 0px 0px 10px #000;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

The above code is just ignored by all browsers. It does not appear on the page, nor on "Inspect Element" in the browser. Any ideas? This is the code I am using on the template, which I am calling on the custom page.

```
<div class="frontpage_tile">
    <a class="block" href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>" data-icon="&#xe00b;">
      <?php the_post_thumbnail('home-thumb'); ?>
      <span class="caption">
          <?php the_title(); ?>
      </span>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Caching issue perhaps?

Comment: Not sure, restarted the computer already and tried Firefox, Chrome and IE.

Comment: Try the key-combination CTRL (CMD on mac) + SHIFT + R, or CTRL + F5 for IE. This will clear your local cache while refreshing the page.

Comment: Without seeing the site we can't help much further.

Comment: maybe tags have already existing class?

Comment: The stylesheet you are loading does not contain `.block .caption` anywhere within it. Are you sure you are loading the correct file?

Comment: I can see all the css you said didn't applied in chrome's web dev tool. So caching issue on your end I assume

Comment: I can confirm what IndieRok says.

Comment: For caching open dev tools, click the settings cog at the top and check 'disable cache (while devtools is open)'. Then refresh

Comment: My guess is that the stylesheet is still cached by the WP install and needs to be flushed or the new version hasn't been uploaded as I can't see those classes in the current version.

Comment: I haven't done anything other than the usual editing of the stylesheet in Wordpress admin, so I assume the cache must be flushed then?

Comment: Saved possibly but that doesn't mean (AFAIK) that you don't have to do a WP cache flush to get the CSS sheet to reload.

Comment: I can see the styles in question in Firebug on my end. Try clearing the cache and closing your browser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just scanned your website with wpscan for the sake of it, and here's your problem:

```
[+] Interesting header: CF-RAY: 15644be6d86308d8-LHR
[+] Interesting header: SERVER: cloudflare-nginx
[+] Interesting header: X-CF-POWERED-BY: WP 1.3.14
[+] Interesting header: X-POWERED-BY: PHP/5.5.14
```

You're using Cloudflare :) , just login into your Control Panel and enable Development mode.

**I'll leave the old answer below, just in case someone finds this question and wants to know how to do a bit of troubleshooting:**

If you go at the top of your stylesheet you'll see the following comments:

```
/*
Theme Name: Twenty Ten
Theme URI: http://wordpress.org/
Author: the WordPress team
[...]
Version: 1.4
[...]
*/
```

Just change your number version and Wordpress now will serve the stylesheet with the new version number, forcing your browser to re-download it, otherwise while you're under development you can register your CSS in that way (which is really handy):

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'main-style', get_stylesheet_uri(), array(), time() );
```

This enforces to append a timestamp on the CSS as query variable, so your browser believes that's a new file and the new fresh CSS gets downloaded every time you refresh the page.

Generally the `CTRL/CMD + SHIFT + R` works without any problem, if you still see your old CSS even with those changes one of these is probably what is causing problems:

- Your website is using Cloudflare and you forgot to enable dev mode
- Your wordpress is running a caching plugin
- You're uploading your file in the wrong place

Cheers

Comment: a cooment about adding timestamp to css/image file query, rather than `time()` you might want to use `filemtime('path_to_file')` instead so "redownload" only happens when the file's changed.

Comment: Thank you, that works. Didn't know Cloudflare can actually affect it!

Comment: @rlatief true, if we are going for the elegant way I would suggest `filemtime()` too :)

Comment: @zzwyb89 no worries, I had same problem and I lost 2 hours looking into it, I learned the hard way to keep development off Cloudflare ;)

Answer (score -1):

in the css addd the `!important` syntax after the lines like this

```
.some_class_to_edit{
   text-decoration: none !important;
}
```

And also try to check that there is no another `css` coming after that, which can override it